# Modals are immediately closed with Bootstrap CSS

Tags: css, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap

I am facing an issue where the Twitter Bootstrapp CSS opens my animation with fade and immediately closes it. I do not know why this happens, can anyone help?

**Update:** Apperantly, the bootstrap.css already has the Modals implemented. So, using both of them makes a trouble. Leaving this for future searchers.

JSFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/GB9ud/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-9">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" lang="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js" lang="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-tooltip.js" lang="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js" lang="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-modal.js" lang="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
    <title>Library Management System</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-book-id="1" href="#extendbook" class="btn">Extend</a>
    <div id="extendbook" class="modal hide fade">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <a data-dismiss="modal" class="close">×</a>
            <h3>Modal header</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>One fine body…</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm guessing there's something going on that won't be apparent from just the markup you're showing us. Can you link to the site as well or create a jsfiddle?

Comment: @kinakuta created a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/GB9ud/

Comment: Yes, but even the conditions are same, it does not happen on [Twitter's example page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)

Comment: I tested your code and it only happened because you're including the script twice. Once inside the bootstrap.js file (which comes with all of the plugins) and again with the loose bootstrap-modal.js script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling the modal twice so it's loading then closing then loading again

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this, I was experiencing the same problem, and the solution in my case was to upgrade my version of jQuery to 1.9 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem working on a project with asp.NET.
I was using bootstrap 3.0.1 solved it downgrading to Bootstrap 2.3.2.